# Orientability between diffeomorphic surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, orientation

From Do Carmo's Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces, 2nd edition,

[image]

Now, when I tried to prove this, I reached this point:

[image]

Up until this box, I couldn't understand the philosophy behind these steps, the definition of $V_{\alpha}$ and $V_{\beta}$ containing all these inverses, compositions, and intersections made me very dizzy, I've tried thinking about them for a good while and I'm still lost, if anyone could guide me through the logic behind these steps I'd really appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: In broad outline, I think he is trying to say that $\det(x_\alpha^{-1}\circ x_\beta) = \det((\varphi^{-1}\circ x_\alpha)^{-1}\circ(\varphi^{-1}\circ x_\beta))$ but there are complications due to intersection of domains and locality of the diffeomorphism.

Comment: I mean the determinants of the derivatives of these maps of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try to get some intuition by starting with an easier problem: Let $S_2$ be an orientable regular surface and $\varphi : S_1 \to S_2$ be a (global) diffeomorphism. Prove $S_1$ is orientable.

In this case, we know $S_2$ is a regular surface, so it is covered by a family of coordinate charts $\{(U_\alpha,\mathbf x_\alpha)\}$ each $\mathbf x_\alpha : U_\alpha \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to S_2$. If two charts overlap, $p \in \mathbf x_\alpha (U_\alpha) \cap \mathbf x_\beta (U_\beta)$, we can write the transition function $\mathbf x_\beta^{-1} \circ \mathbf x_\alpha : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$. Then since $S_2$ is orientable, we have $\text{det}(d(\mathbf x_\beta^{-1} \circ \mathbf x_\alpha)) > 0$.

Assuming that $\varphi$ is a (global) diffeomorphism, we can cover $S_1$ by a family of coordinate charts $\{\big(U_\alpha,(\varphi^{-1} \circ \mathbf x_\alpha)\big)\}$ each $\varphi^{-1} \circ \mathbf x_\alpha : U_\alpha \subset\mathbb{R}^2 \to S_1$. If two charts overlap, $q \in (\varphi^{-1} \circ \mathbf x_\alpha) (U_\alpha) \cap (\varphi^{-1} \circ \mathbf x_\beta) (U_\beta)$, we can calculate the transition function:
$$  (\varphi^{-1} \circ \mathbf x_\beta)^{-1} \circ (\varphi^{-1} \circ \mathbf x_\alpha) = \mathbf x_\beta\circ \varphi \circ \varphi^{-1} \circ \mathbf x_\alpha = (\mathbf x_\beta^{-1} \circ \mathbf x_\alpha)$$

So it is clear that $S_1$ is orientable.

--

Returning to the question you posted, the difference is that $\varphi$ is only a *local* diffeomorphism, which do Carmo defines on page 89. The logic behind the solution you posted is that the intersection $(\varphi^{-1} \circ \mathbf x_\alpha) (U_\alpha) \cap (\varphi^{-1} \circ \mathbf x_\beta) (U_\beta)\subset S_1$ might not be an open set on which $\varphi$ is a diffeomorphism. What we can find instead is for any point in the intersection is a neighborhood $V\subset S_1$ on which $\varphi$ *is* a diffeomorphism on its image. Then the intersection $V \cap (\varphi^{-1} \circ \mathbf x_\alpha) (U_\alpha) \cap (\varphi^{-1} \circ \mathbf x_\beta) (U_\beta)$ is in the intersection of two charts and also $\varphi$ is a diffeomorphism, letting us use that $\varphi^{-1}$ is well-defined and differentiable.

The problem with the solution you posted is that it presumes $\varphi^{-1} : S_2 \to S_1$ is well-defined on every $\mathbf x_\alpha(U_\alpha)$. This is cannot be assumed true, so the family $\varphi^{-1} \circ \mathbf x_\alpha : U_\alpha\to S_1$ might not be well-defined (An example of when this fails is the coordinate chart & local diffeomorphism $\varphi(u,v) = (\sin u \cos v,\cos u\cos v,\sin v)$ on all of $\mathbb{R}$ to the unit sphere). This might be easier to solve by using unit normal vectors on $S_2$ (pg 106-110) together with the characterization that $d\varphi$ is full rank (pg 89).

Comment: Thank you for the very clear explanation, I understand it now!